# Handling exceptions with in velocity template

Tags: velocity

How do I handle exceptions with in velocity template when I am processing say 100 records in a loop. If I get an exception while processing one record then I should be able to continue with the next record. Is this possible with velocity template or this needs to be handled in java.

What is the best way to handle exceptions when using velocity templates?

Thanks for your clarification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no exception flow control handling inside the template itself. If an exception is thrown, the rendering of the current template will stop and the exception will be logged and displayed in the output. The overall philosophy is to try to contain the exceptions to the Java objects methods.
For instance, instead of exposing `Object MyObject.mayThow()` into the template, you can use a wrapper:

```
class MyWrapper
{
    bool doesntThrow()
    {
        try
        {
            return mayThrow()
        }
        catch (MyException e)
        {
            // log it if necessary
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

And in the template:

```
#foreach($i in $items)
    ## ...
    #set ($obj = $i.doesntThrow())
    #if($obj)
        ## ...
    #end
#end
```

Instead of a wrapper, you can also use a `MethodExceptionEventHandler`:

```
package mypackage;
import org.apache.velocity.app.event.MethodExceptionEventHandler;

public class MyHandler implements MethodExceptionEventHandler
{
    public Object methodException(Class claz, String method, Exception e) throws Exception
    {
        // for instance, return null as a convention
        if (claz == MyObject.class && method.equals("doesThrow")) return null;
        // something else happened...
        else throw e;
    }
}
```

And you can then directly call `mayThrow()` in the template:

```
#foreach($i in $items)
    ## ...
    #set ($obj = $i.mayThrow())
    #if($obj)
        ## ...
    #end
#end
```

Of course you have to register your event handler in your `velocity.properties` file:

```
eventhandler.methodexception.class = mypackage.MyHandler
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But I need to register my event handler to EventCartridge